# MSSQL Unicode Data

Tags: php, sql-server, export

I'm trying to save a MSSQL database by using PHP. I chose to use phpMSadmin to do so. The problem is that I'm getting: "Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier." So I've checked the code and apparently the problem is here:

```
$table_query = @mssql_query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table . ';') or die(throwSQLError('unable to retrieve table data'));
```

The whole code is this:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['skippreview']) && !empty($_POST['doexport']))
    $skipheader = true;

include('inc/header.php');

mssql_select_db($_SESSION['database']);

if(!empty($_POST['doexport']))
{
    $texttypes = array('binary','char','nchar','varchar','nvarchar');
    $masterquery = '';

    if(!empty($_POST['dropdb']))
        $masterquery .= ('DROP DATABASE ' . $_SESSION['database'] . ';' . "\n");

    if(!empty($_POST['createdb']))
        $masterquery .= ('CREATE DATABASE ' . $_SESSION['database'] . ';' . "\n");

    if(!empty($_POST['useentry']))
        $masterquery .= ('USE ' . $_SESSION['database'] . ';' . "\n");

    $tablecount = count($_POST['tables']);

    for($counter = 0; $counter < $tablecount; $counter++)
    {
        $table = $_POST['tables'][$counter];

        if(!empty($_POST['structure']))
        {
            $tablequery = ('CREATE TABLE ' . $table);
            $columns = array();
            $tablesep = explode('.',$table);

            if(substr_count($_POST['tables'][$counter],'.') > 0)
            {
                $colquery = ('sp_columns @table_name = N\'' . $tablesep[1] . '\'');
                $colquery .= (', @table_owner = N\'' . $tablesep[0] . '\'');
            }
            else
                $colquery = ('sp_columns @table_name = N\'' . $tablesep[0] . '\'');

            $column_query = @mssql_query($colquery) or die(throwSQLError('unable to retrieve column data'));

            if(mssql_num_rows($column_query) > 0)
                $tablequery .= ' (';

            while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($column_query))
            {
                // Start Column Conversion

                $colspec = ($row['COLUMN_NAME'] . ' ' . strtoupper($row['TYPE_NAME']));

                if(in_array($row['TYPE_NAME'],$texttypes))
                    $colspec .= ('(' . $row['PRECISION'] . ')');

                if(!$row['NULLABLE'])
                    $colspec .= ' NOT NULL';

                if($row['COLUMN_DEF'] != '')
                    $colspec .= (' DEFAULT ' . $row['COLUMN_DEF']);

                $tablequery .= (', ' . $colspec);

                // End Column Conversion
            }

            if(mssql_num_rows($column_query) > 0)
                $tablequery .= ')';

            $tablequery = str_replace('(, ','(',$tablequery);
            $masterquery .= ($tablequery . ';' . "\n");
        }

        if(!empty($_POST['data']))
        {
            $table_query = @mssql_query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table . ';') or die(throwSQLError('unable to retrieve table data'));
            while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($table_query))
            {
                if(!isset($schema))
                {
                    $schema = array();

                    foreach($row AS $key => $value)
                        $schema[] = $key;
                }

                $values = array();
                foreach($schema AS $col)
                    if(is_numeric($row[$col]))
                        $values[] = ('\'' . str_replace('\'','\'\'',$row[$col]) . '\'');
                    else if(!empty($_POST['base64']))
                        $values[] = ('\'' . base64_encode(str_replace('\'','\'\'',$row[$col])) . '\'');
                    else
                        $values[] = ('\'' . str_replace('\'','\'\'',$row[$col]) . '\'');

                $masterquery .= ('INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' (' . implode(',',$schema) . ') VALUES (' . implode(',',$values) . ');' . "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['procedures']))
    {
        foreach($_POST['procedures'] AS $value)
        {
            $lines = array();
            $doit = false;

            $data_query = @mssql_query('sp_helptext \'' . $value . '\'') or die(throwSQLError('unable to retrieve procedure'));
            if(!@mssql_num_rows($data_query))
            {
                $schema_query = @mssql_query('SELECT SPECIFIC_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = \'' . $value . '\';');
                if($schema_query)
                {
                    $schema_array = mssql_fetch_array($schema_query);
                    $value = ($schema_array['SPECIFIC_SCHEMA'] . '.' . $value);

                    unset($data_query);
                    $data_query = @mssql_query('sp_helptext \'' . $value . '\'') or die(throwSQLError('unable to retrieve procedure'));

                    if(@mssql_num_rows($data_query))
                        $doit = true;
                }
            }
            else
                $doit = true;

            if($doit)
            {
                while($row = mssql_fetch_array($data_query))
                    $lines[] = $row['Text'];

                $masterquery .= (implode('',$lines) . "\n");
            }

            unset($lines,$doit);
        }
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['views']))
    {
        foreach($_POST['views'] AS $value)
        {
            $lines = array();
            $doit = false;

            $data_query = @mssql_query('sp_helptext \'' . $value . '\'') or die(throwSQLError('unable to retrieve procedure'));
            if(!@mssql_num_rows($data_query))
            {
                $schema_query = @mssql_query('SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_NAME = \'' . $value . '\';');
                if($schema_query)
                {
                    $schema_array = mssql_fetch_array($schema_query);
                    $value = ($schema_array['TABLE_SCHEMA'] . '.' . $value);

                    unset($data_query);
                    $data_query = @mssql_query('sp_helptext \'' . $value . '\'') or die(throwSQLError('unable to retrieve view'));

                    if(@mssql_num_rows($data_query))
                        $doit = true;
                }
            }
            else
                $doit = true;

            if($doit)
            {
                while($row = mssql_fetch_array($data_query))
                    $lines[] = $row['Text'];

                $masterquery .= (implode('',$lines) . "\n");
            }

            unset($lines,$doit);
        }
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['functions']))
    {
        foreach($_POST['functions'] AS $value)
        {
            $lines = array();

            $data_query = @mssql_query('sp_helptext \'' . $value . '\'') or die(throwSQLError('unable to retrieve function'));
            if($data_query)
            {
                while($row = mssql_fetch_array($data_query))
                    $lines[] = $row['Text'];

                $masterquery .= (implode('',$lines) . "\n");

                unset($lines);
            }
        }
    }

    $masterquery = rtrim($masterquery);

    if(empty($_POST['skippreview']))
    {
        echo '<form name="form1" method="post" action="database_export_download.php">';
        echo '<textarea name="data" rows="30" cols="75">';

        echo($masterquery);

        echo '</textarea>';

        echo '<br><br><input type="submit" value="Save to File">';
        echo '</form>';

        include('inc/footer.php');
    }
    else
    {
        header('Content-type: application/x-download');
         header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $_SESSION['database'] . '.sql"');
         header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($masterquery));
         echo($masterquery);
        exit;
    }
}

$tables = array();

$db_query = mssql_query('sp_tables') or die(throwSQLError('unable to retrieve list of tables'));

while($row = mssql_fetch_array($db_query))
{
    if($row['TABLE_TYPE'] == 'TABLE' && $row['TABLE_NAME'] != 'dtproperties')
    {
        if($row['TABLE_OWNER'] != 'dbo')
            $tables[] = ($row['TABLE_OWNER'] . '.' . $row['TABLE_NAME']);
        else
            $tables[] = $row['TABLE_NAME'];
    }
}

?>

<script language="javascript">
function doCheck(mode)
{
    for(counter = 0; counter < document.form1.tablecount.value; counter++)
        document.forms['form1'].elements['tables[]'][counter].checked = mode;
}

function doCheckProcedures(mode)
{
    for(counter = 0; counter < document.form1.procedurecount.value; counter++)
        document.forms['form1'].elements['procedures[]'][counter].checked = mode;
}

function doCheckViews(mode)
{
    for(counter = 0; counter < document.form1.viewcount.value; counter++)
        document.forms['form1'].elements['views[]'][counter].checked = mode;
}

function doCheckFunctions(mode)
{
    for(counter = 0; counter < document.form1.functioncount.value; counter++)
        document.forms['form1'].elements['functions[]'][counter].checked = mode;
}
</script>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="database_export.php">
<input type="hidden" name="doexport" value="yes">
<table width="350" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style="border: 1px solid">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="3" style="background: #D0DCE0"><b>Tables</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background: #D0DCE0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" style="background: #D0DCE0">
            <b>Table</b>
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="background: #D0DCE0">
            <b>Records</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $totalrecords = 0;
        $toggle = true;
        $colors = array('#DDDDDD','#CCCCCC');

        if(empty($_POST['tables']))
            $_POST['tables'] = array();

        foreach($tables AS $row)
        {
            if($toggle)
                $bg = $colors[0];
            else
                $bg = $colors[1];

            $toggle = !$toggle;

            if(substr_count($row,'.') > 0)
                $record_query = mssql_query('SELECT count(*) AS itemcount FROM ' . $row);
            else
                $record_query = mssql_query('SELECT count(*) AS itemcount FROM [' . $row . ']');

            $record_array = mssql_fetch_array($record_query);
            $records = $record_array['itemcount'];
            $totalrecords += $records;

            echo '<tr>';

            if(in_array($row,$_POST['tables']))
                echo('<td align="center" style="background: ' . $bg . '"><input type="checkbox" name="tables[]" value="' . $row . '" checked></td>');
            else
                echo('<td align="center" style="background: ' . $bg . '"><input type="checkbox" name="tables[]" value="' . $row . '"></td>');

            echo('<td style="background: ' . $bg . '">' . $row . '</td>');
            echo('<td style="background: ' . $bg . '">' . number_format($records) . '</td>');
            echo '</tr>';

            unset($record_query,$record_array,$records);
        }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="2" style="background: #EAEAEA">
            <b>Total Row Count:</b>
        </td>
        <td align="right" style="background: #EAEAEA">
            <?php echo number_format($totalrecords); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="background: #D0DCE0" nowrap>
            Select Tables:&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:doCheck(true);">All</a> / <a href="javascript:doCheck(false);">None</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br>

<?php
    $procs = array();
    $views = array();
    $functions = array();

    $proc_query = @mssql_query('sp_help') or die(throwSQLError('unable to retrieve list of stored procedures'));
    while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($proc_query))
    {
        if($row['Object_type'] == 'stored procedure' && ($row['Owner'] == 'dbo' || $_SETTINGS['showsysdata']))
            $procs[] = $row['Name'];
        else if($row['Object_type'] == 'view' && ($row['Owner'] == 'dbo' || $_SETTINGS['showsysdata']))
            $views[] = $row['Name'];
        else if(substr_count($row['Object_type'],'function') > 0 && ($row['Owner'] == 'dbo' || $_SETTINGS['showsysdata']))
            $functions[] = $row['Name'];
    }
?>

<table width="350" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style="border: 1px solid">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="background: #D0DCE0">
            <b>Stored Procedures</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background: #D0DCE0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" style="background: #D0DCE0">
            <b>Name</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $toggle = true;
        $colors = array('#DDDDDD','#CCCCCC');

        foreach($procs AS $key => $value)
        {
            $row['Name'] = $value;

            if($toggle)
                $bg = $colors[0];
            else
                $bg = $colors[1];

            $toggle = !$toggle;

            echo '<tr>';
            echo('<td align="center" style="background: ' . $bg . '"><input type="checkbox" name="procedures[]" value="' . $row['Name'] . '"></td>');
            echo('<td style="background: ' . $bg . '" nowrap>' . $row['Name'] . '</td>');
            echo '</tr>';

            unset($row);
        }

        if(count($procs) == 0)
            echo '<tr><td align="center" colspan="3" style="background: #DDDDDD">No Stored Procedures</td></tr>';
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="background: #D0DCE0">
            Select Procedures:&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:doCheckProcedures(true);">All</a> / <a href="javascript:doCheckProcedures(false);">None</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br>

<table width="350" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style="border: 1px solid">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="background: #D0DCE0">
            <b>Views</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background: #D0DCE0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" style="background: #D0DCE0">
            <b>Name</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $toggle = true;
        $colors = array('#DDDDDD','#CCCCCC');

        foreach($views AS $key => $value)
        {
            $row['Name'] = $value;

            if($toggle)
                $bg = $colors[0];
            else
                $bg = $colors[1];

            $toggle = !$toggle;

            echo '<tr>';
            echo('<td align="center" style="background: ' . $bg . '"><input type="checkbox" name="views[]" value="' . $row['Name'] . '"></td>');
            echo('<td style="background: ' . $bg . '" nowrap>' . $row['Name'] . '</td>');
            echo '</tr>';

            unset($row);
        }

        if(count($procs) == 0)
            echo '<tr><td align="center" colspan="3" style="background: #DDDDDD">No Views</td></tr>';
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="background: #D0DCE0">
            Select Views:&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:doCheckViews(true);">All</a> / <a href="javascript:doCheckViews(false);">None</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br>

<table width="350" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style="border: 1px solid">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="background: #D0DCE0">
            <b>Functions</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background: #D0DCE0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" style="background: #D0DCE0">
            <b>Name</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $toggle = true;
        $colors = array('#DDDDDD','#CCCCCC');

        foreach($functions AS $key => $value)
        {
            $row['Name'] = $value;

            if($toggle)
                $bg = $colors[0];
            else
                $bg = $colors[1];

            $toggle = !$toggle;

            echo '<tr>';
            echo('<td align="center" style="background: ' . $bg . '"><input type="checkbox" name="functions[]" value="' . $row['Name'] . '"></td>');
            echo('<td style="background: ' . $bg . '" nowrap>' . $row['Name'] . '</td>');
            echo '</tr>';

            unset($row);
        }

        if(count($functions) == 0)
            echo '<tr><td align="center" colspan="2" style="background: #DDDDDD">No Functions</td></tr>';
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="background: #D0DCE0">
            Select Functions:&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:doCheckFunctions(true);">All</a> / <a href="javascript:doCheckFunctions(false);">None</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br>

<input type="hidden" name="tablecount" value="<?php echo(count($tables)); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="procedurecount" value="<?php echo(count($procs)); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="viewcount" value="<?php echo(count($views)); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="functioncount" value="<?php echo(count($functions)); ?>">

<table width="350" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style="border: 1px solid">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="background: #D0DCE0">
            <b>Export Options</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" style="background: #CCCCCC" valign="top" nowrap>
            Selection:
        </td>
        <td style="background: #CCCCCC" nowrap>
            <input type="checkbox" name="structure" value="yes"> Structure<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="data" value="yes"> Data
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" style="background: #CCCCCC" valign="top" nowrap>
            Preparation:
        </td>
        <td style="background: #CCCCCC" nowrap>
            <input type="checkbox" name="dropdb" value="yes"> Drop Database First<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="createdb" value="yes"> Use Create Database<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="useentry" value="yes"> Add "USE" Database Switch
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" style="background: #CCCCCC" valign="top" nowrap>
            Method:
        </td>
        <td style="background: #CCCCCC" nowrap>
            <input type="checkbox" name="base64" value="yes"> Base-64 Encode Strings<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="skippreview" value="yes"> Skip Export Preview
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="2" style="background: #D0DCE0">
            <input type="submit" value="Export">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php include('inc/footer.php'); ?>
```

Is there any possible way to fix this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try to Google the error you got before posting it here? https://www.google.co.il/search?q=+%22Unicode+data+in+a+Unicode-only+collation+or+ntext+data+cannot+be+sent+to+clients+using+DB-Library+%28such+as+ISQL%29+or+ODBC+version+3.7+or+earlier.%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: Please post the code here.

Comment: Posted the code here now.